# color command output with argument relative true or relative false?

Tags: g1ant

I am having a red desktop and I took a mouse position on it, but G1ANT has a white background in its software. When I take either relative false or relative true in this particular robot, it gives me the same output i.e. FFFFFF which is white. But why, for relative false it should give output for red colour?

```
color position 863⫽592 relative
dialog ♥result
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are missing an argument value for `relative`. It should be either `true` or `false`.

If you want to get the color of the desktop relatively to the active window (which is G1ANT.Studio in your example), choose Insert from the menu and Mouse Position. In the appearing window "Absolute position?", select "no". Your code should look like the following and in the position argument, should be your inserted mouse position.

```
color position 863⫽592 relative true
dialog ♥result
```

If you want it to be in absolute position, choose otherwise and set `relative` argument to `false`.